# Color Picker changing layout color

Tags: java, android-studio

I used this library: https://github.com/kristiyanP/colorpicker in order to have a color picker on my app.
My problem is when I click cancel and click again the color picker shows extra 2 rows in dialog
This is my code for onOptionItemSelected

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.color:
                openColorPicker();
                break;
        }
    return true;
}
```

openColorPicker

```
public void openColorPicker(){
        final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(this);

        color.add("#EF9A9A");
        color.add("#F48FB1");
        color.add("#CE93D8");
        color.add("#B39DDB");
        color.add("#9FA8DA");
        color.add("#90CAF9");
        color.add("#E6EE9C");
        color.add("#FFAB91");
        color.add("#E0E0E0");
        color.add("#ba2d65");

        colorPicker.setColors(color).setColumns(5)
                .setRoundColorButton(true).setOnFastChooseColorListener(new ColorPicker.OnFastChooseColorListener() {
            @Override
            public void setOnFastChooseColorListener(int position, int Color) {
                Colors = color.get(position).toString();
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color);
                editText1.setBackgroundColor(Color);
                editText2.setBackgroundColor(Color);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        }).show();

    }
```

Comment: any feedback after the answer below?

Comment: its work @Lino i just put it as global so its show extra two rows thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you define the `color` variable at the class level. Try to define it inside the `openColorPicker()` method, just like this:

```
public void openColorPicker(){
        final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(this);

        ArrayList<String> color = new ArrayList<>();
        color.add("#EF9A9A");
        color.add("#F48FB1");
        color.add("#CE93D8");
        color.add("#B39DDB");
        color.add("#9FA8DA");
        color.add("#90CAF9");
        color.add("#E6EE9C");
        color.add("#FFAB91");
        color.add("#E0E0E0");
        color.add("#ba2d65");
....
}
```